# How to read variable from third level struct?

Tags: swift, struct, tableview

i know how to access “struct Course” variables and get them to tableview. I do it like this:

```
var event = [Course]()
//some code left out
let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFromWeb.self, from: data)
self.event = courses.data
//some code left out
```

And then in tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell") as? UserEventsTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.idLabel.text = event[indexPath.row].id
        cell.nameLabel.text = event[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
```

But i cant figure out the way to access Cover variables and get for example source value and add it to tableView. Like i did with Course variables.
My struct is here: (credits to user Vadian who coded this using my JSON.)

```
struct JsonFromWeb: Codable {
    let data: [Course]
}

struct Course: Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case attendingCount = "attending_count"
        case id, name, cover
    }
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let attendingCount: Int
    let cover: Cover?
}

struct Cover : Codable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case offsetX = "offset_x"
        case offsetY = "offset_y"
        case source, id
    }
    let offsetX: Int
    let offsetY: Int
    let source: String
    let id: String
}
```

Hope to find help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward:

To access `source` in `cover` use

```
event[indexPath.row].cover?.source
```